# Unique Record Identifier of Addressbook contact + SQLite database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, addressbook

I am developing one application that requires records from `Addressbook`, I need all details of contact, plus I am using google service to get lat-long of contact address and storing this details to SQLite.

Now the questions are:
1). Which one is better option, storing unique record identifier of contact in SQLite or storing all  details of contact?
2). If your answer is **identifier** then will this unique record identifier **refer the same** record every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1). Which one is better option, storing unique record identifier of contact in SQLite or storing all details of contact?**

*I would say there is no need to store the whole data, since that is already stored in the device, so a simple identifier will do.*

**2). If your answer is identifier then will this unique record identifier refer the same record every time?**

*Yes, it must refer to the same record every time, which is why it is a unique identifier.*

Additionally I would recommend reading the section of unique identifiers in the AddressBook framework directly from the source: [Apple Address Book Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/DirectInteraction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH6-SW1)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

ABRecordID a.k.a. the unique identifier is a good way to identify each record. However, apple documentation does states some noteworthy points about the ABRecordID returned by this API.

> Every record in the Address Book database has a unique record identifier. This identifier always refers to the same record, unless that record is deleted or the data is reset. Record identifiers can be safely passed between threads. They are not guaranteed to remain the same across devices.

Thus, to answer your questions
1). Which one is better option, storing unique record identifier of contact in SQLite or storing all details of contact?

*The minimal details that I would suggest you to store in your SQLite DB are: first name, last name, creation date and record ID*

The reason is, again mentioned in the apple documentation:

> The recommended way to keep a long-term reference to a particular record is to store the first and last name, or a hash of the first and last name, in addition to the identifier. When you look up a record by ID, compare the record’s name to your stored name. If they don’t match, use the stored name to find the record, and store the new ID for the record.

Note that, I have inserted the creation date the sqLite DB as well since the user might change th name of the contact, but even on a device **RESET**, creation date remains same.

2). If your answer is identifier then will this unique record identifier refer the same record every time?

*While explaining your first question, I think I have answered this question as well.*

[Though I have pasted most of the content here, its always advised to read the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/DirectInteraction.html)

Answer (score 1):

The addressbook unique identifier is not same always. it has the possibility of changing if you run some sync apps like google contacts of TAPP Addressbook as it get the contacts deleted and add again. best ways is to generate some hash code like combining all properties and then check in db if one not match then delete from sqlite that not matches and add new one in db.

remember if you are on a single device then no problem for an id. but if your contacts are being communicated with any server of device like mac. then you need to find a better solution. i found one that i've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Record identifier always refers to the same record, unless that record is deleted or the data is reset. It is not guaranteed to remain the same across devices. [Address Book Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/DirectInteraction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH6-SW2) prefers

> The recommended way to keep a long-term reference to a particular record is to store the first and last name, or a hash of the first and last name, in addition to the identifier. When you look up a record by ID, compare the record’s name to your stored name. If they don’t match, use the stored name to find the record, and store the new ID for the record.